# ¿Como enviar un formulario (submit) presionando etiquetas <a> y se reciba en otra pagina los datos que contengan los inputs? JS y HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, web

Quiero enviar un formulario con la etiqueta < a >  y que se mande la información que contienen los inputs
(En el formulario hay una etiqueta botón que contiene un valor traído desde la base de datos y quiero que ese valor llegue a la pagina del action=""
¿Es posible?

```
 <?php
            $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias_deportes");
            $consulta->execute();
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php foreach ($consulta as $valor) { ?>
             <form action="../noticias/noticia.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden" name="etiquetas" value="<?php echo $valor['Etiqueta']; ?>">
                <div class="card mb-3" style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.281)">
                    <h5 class="titulo-t"><?php echo $valor['Titulo_noticia']; ?></h5>
                    <img src="<?php echo $valor['Imagen']; ?>" class="card-img-top imagen-t" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="descp-t"><?php echo $valor['Descripcion_aviso']; ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?php echo $valor['Fecha']; ?></small></p>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $valor['id']; ?>">LEER MÁS</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let link = document.getElementById("submit-link");

link.addEventListener("click", submitForm, false);

function submitForm() {
  let theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");
  theForm.submit(); 
}
```

```html
<form id="theForm" action="/" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="someValue">
    Submit
  </button>
  
 <br>
 <br>
 
 <a id="submit-link" href="#">Un link para enviar</a>
</form>
```

Para enviar un formulario haciendo click en un link , puedes usar JS para disparar el evento submit del formulario al hacer click sobre este, para el boton, si le agregas el atributo name y asignas un value="algunValor", este valor se envia junto al resto de inputs

Edit: agregue un ejemplo para que lo veas mas claro

Comment: ¿Qué valor coloco en HREF=""? porque cuando lo dejo sin href y doy click no hace nada, incluso colocando href="#" lo que hace es redireccioarme a # y no envia el formulario

Comment: Añadi codigo de ejemplo, tal vez asi lo ves mas claro